# Batch file stuck while unziping large files, when called from windows service..!

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, service, windows-services

I have a windows service that calls a batch file. Batch file then calls commands to zip and unzip text files. Sometimes, while unzipping large files (approx. = 900MB) the process get stuck in between and then I have to stop windows service to release the process.Can anyone please suggest some solution to this problem?

I use following code to call batch file and retrieve return code from it:

```
objProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@out_Batch_File_Name); 
objProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
objProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
objProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
objProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 

process = new Process(); 
process.Start Info = objProcessStartInfo; 
process.Start(); 
process.WaitForExit(); 
returnCode = process.ExitCode;
```

Comment: "get stuck in between" means the zip process is not finish yet, right ? do you get any exception ?

Comment: Yes, zip process does not finish and I'm not getting any exception.

Comment: You must try to find the problem on another process. I think the problem is not in your dotnet code.